# Partial derivatives

Tags: partial-derivative

For $F(x,y)=ye^{x^2-y}$ find $F_x, F_{xx}, F_y, F_{xy}$ (partial derivatives)

I'm not sure if these are correct, but this is what I got:

$F_x=2xye^{x^2-y}$

$F_{xx}=4xye^{x^2-y}$

$F_y=-e^{x^2-y}$

$F_{xy}=-2xe^{x^2-y}$

Comment: Only $F_x$ is computed correctly.

Comment: You need to use product rule for $F_{xx}$.

Comment: The product rule will come into play for all but the first one.

Answer (score 2):

Only $F_x$ is correct.

For $F_y$ you get
$$
F_y=e^{x^2-y}-ye^{x^2-y}
$$
using the product rule and the chain rule.

Similarly,
$$
F_{xx}=2ye^{x^2-y}+4x^2ye^{x^2-y}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Only $F_x=2xye^{x^2-y}$ is correct. Using both the product rule and chain rule, we get that $F_{xx}=(4x^2+2)ye^{x^2-y}$. Proceeding as you did for $F_x$, but now treating $x$ as a constant and taking the derivative with respect to $y$, we obtain $F_y=(1-y)e^{x^2-y}$. Lastly, using the product and chain rule, we obtain that $F_{xy}=F_{yx}=2xe^{x^2-y}-2xye^{x^2-y}$. If there are any steps you are confused about, I can write out the work.